# Multiple users click the button of django web app at the same time

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I wanted to know, in Django if there are multiple users clicking the Button of web-app at the same time, so will it create a conflict?

For example. There is a "next sample" button to pull the sample data from database, so if multiple users at the same time click the next sample button, will there will be any conflicts(like two users got the same sample data set?). I have researched about it but could not get the clear answer, however i believe that Django application creates the individual sessions for the request and it wont overlap the requests.

Comment: This should be handled by the sessions

Comment: So there will be no overlaps in the request created by multiple users?

Comment: No there wont be

Comment: just check if the session middleware is activated https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Yes that's activated.

Comment: Then you are fine. Take care!